# Lookup two lists in one resource

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, cloudwatch-alarms

I am trying to create cloudwatch alerts for a NLB in aws for UnHealthyHostCountmetric

I have the NLBs defined as so:

```
variable "lb" {
  type    = list
  default = [
"net/lb01/bb087",
"net/lb01/bb088"
]
}
```

I have the target groups defined as so:

```
variable "lb_tg" {
  type    = list
  default = [
    "targetgroup/newtargetlkinjk/3dac",
    "targetgroup/newtargetlkinjk/3d0d"
  ]
}
```

I then use datasource on them as so:

```
data "aws_lb_target_group" "my_lb_target_group" {

  for_each = toset(var.lb_tg)

  tags = {
    name = each.key
  }
}

data "aws_lb" "my_lbs" {

  for_each = toset(var.lb)

  tags = {
    name = each.key
  }
}
```

I am then trying to use both in an alarm as such

```
resource "aws_cloudwatch_metric_alarm" "nlb-target-unhealthy-warning" {

  for_each = data.aws_lb_target_group.my_lb_target_group

  alarm_name          = "nlb-target-unhealthy-warning-for-${each.key}"
  comparison_operator = "GreaterThanThreshold"
  evaluation_periods  = "3"
  metric_name         = "UnHealthyHostCount"
  namespace           = "AWS/NetworkELB"
  dimensions = {
    TargetGroup  = each.key
    LoadBalancer = ???
  }
  period                    = "60"
  statistic                 = "Average"
  threshold                 = "0"
  alarm_description         = "This warning metric monitors unhealthy hosts behind the NLB for ${each.key}"
  actions_enabled           = true
  alarm_actions             = [data.aws_sns_topic.my_sns.arn]
  insufficient_data_actions = []
  treat_missing_data        = "notBreaching"
}
```

Since the alarm is already using for_each = data.aws_lb_target_group.my_lb_target_group , how do i provide it the values in data.aws_lb.my_lbs at the same time, which is needed by dimentions-LoadBalancer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not convinced that your data sources work, as they don't seem to be correct as you can't search LBs nor TGs by tag from what I can tell.

But anyway, I tried to **replicate** the issue, and I assumed that **each NLB has one target group** and your variables `lb` and `lb_tg` are matched in **pairs**,  i.e., `nlb1 - tg1`, `nlb2 - tg2`.

In this case your alarms could be created using `count`:

```
resource "aws_cloudwatch_metric_alarm" "nlb-target-unhealthy-warning" {

  count               =  length(var.lb)

  alarm_name          = "nlb-target-unhealthy-warning-for-${var.lb_tg[count.index]}"
  comparison_operator = "GreaterThanThreshold"
  evaluation_periods  = "3"
  metric_name         = "UnHealthyHostCount"
  namespace           = "AWS/NetworkELB"  
   
  dimensions = {
    TargetGroup  = data.aws_lb_target_group.my_lb_target_group[var.lb_tg[count.index]].arn_suffix
    LoadBalancer = data.aws_lb.my_lbs[var.lb[count.index]].arn_suffix
  }  
  
  period                    = "60"
  statistic                 = "Average"
  threshold                 = "0"
  alarm_description         = "This warning metric monitors unhealthy hosts behind the NLB for ${var.lb_tg[count.index]}"
  actions_enabled           = true
  alarm_actions             = [data.aws_sns_topic.my_sns.arn]
  insufficient_data_actions = []
  treat_missing_data        = "notBreaching"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Given that these load balancer and target group pairs are interrelated, I'd suggest to represent them as a single variable so that the correlation between them is more explicit, like this:

```
variable "target_groups" {
  type = map(object({
    load_balancer = string
    target_group  = string
  }))
}
```

The syntax for defining this variable in the caller would therefore be:

```
  target_groups = {
    lb01 = {
      load_balancer = "net/lb01/bb087"
      target_group  = "targetgroup/newtargetlkinjk/3dac"
    }
    lb02 = {
      load_balancer = "net/lb01/bb088"
      target_group  = "targetgroup/newtargetlkinjk/3d0d"
    }
  }
```

As well as making it easier for a future reader to see which load balancers correspond with which target groups, this also gives a key to use to correlate them both inside your module.

```
resource "aws_cloudwatch_metric_alarm" "nlb-target-unhealthy-warning" {
  for_each = var.target_groups

  alarm_name          = "nlb-target-unhealthy-warning-for-${each.key}"
  comparison_operator = "GreaterThanThreshold"
  evaluation_periods  = "3"
  metric_name         = "UnHealthyHostCount"
  namespace           = "AWS/NetworkELB"
  dimensions = {
    TargetGroup  = each.value.target_group
    LoadBalancer = each.value.load_balancer
  }
  period                    = "60"
  statistic                 = "Average"
  threshold                 = "0"
  alarm_description         = "This warning metric monitors unhealthy hosts behind the NLB for ${each.key}"
  actions_enabled           = true
  alarm_actions             = [data.aws_sns_topic.my_sns.arn]
  insufficient_data_actions = []
  treat_missing_data        = "notBreaching"
}
```

---

If you have a strong reason why you need to keep these two lists separate in the input, you can potentially combine the two together within your module in a local value like this:

```
locals {
  target_groups = [
    for i, lb in var.lb : {
      load_balancer = lb
      target_group  = var.lb_tg[i]
    }
  ]
}
```

You could then use `local.target_groups` in the place where I used `var.target_groups` in my first examples above, with the same effect.